# Recode bytes which cannot be decoded in utf-8 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

reading in from txt files - there is one byte which is causing me issues to encode:

```
    with open(input_filename_and_director, 'rb') as f:
        r = unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
```

Results in an error message:

```
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 26: invalid continuation byte
```

Is there anyway to specify how I want these bytes handled (i.e. to read this byte in as another character?)

Comment: Could you post the file, or a portion of the offending file containing that byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon what you want, try using `unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter="|", errors='replace')` or `unicodecsv.reader(f, delimiter="|", errors='ignore')`. unicodecsv passes through the `errors` parameter to the unicode encoding. See the help for `unicode` or [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more information.